# Example Newsletter of meta sites results in Oops! Something Bad Happened!

Tags: bug, per-site-meta, newsletter

When i follow the link https://stackexchange.com/newsletters/newsletter?site=meta.security.stackexchange.com the Oops! Something Bad Happened! with Panda Style opens.

I also tried the example newsletter of [Android Enthusiats](https://android.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1595/tag-cleanup-for-november-2013) meta which has the same effect. The example newsletter of the main sites seem to work.

**Note**: I have no account on these sites.

Here are the steps to reproduce:

1. Go to https://security.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1446/should-blog-results-be-included-in-the-search-results?noredirect=1 (as an example)
2. Upvote the question -> PopUp "Thanks for the Feedback" opens
3. Click on **see an example newsletter** -> Panda

Comment: I do have an account on security/meta.security and also get the error.

Comment: @Stijn ok, thanks for the info.i have to change my question.

Comment: A clue: according to http://stackexchange.com/newsletters the only Meta with a newsletter is Meta Stack Overflow.

Comment: @Stijn well, it should say "this site has no newsletter" or just redirect to the main stack exchange site, but seeing a [Panda Fail](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DXanObQQTr4) is a failure.

Comment: Correction: the "see an example newsletter" link should link to the parent site newsletter. :)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd I agree that it's a bug, was just pointing it out :)